# How to label specific points in scatterplot

Tags: r, plot, label

I have a scatterplot using this `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(1)    
df <- data.frame(a=sample(1:10,10), b = sample(1:10,10),ID = sample(letters[1:10]))
```

I only want to label the points of `ID [1:5]`.

I tried the code below but it still labelled all of them

```
plot(a~b,data = df)

with(df,text(a~b, labels = ID [1:5]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
with(df[df$ID %in% df$ID[c(1:5)],],text(x = b, y = a, labels = ID, pos = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: The `%in%` is definitely a good suggestion. I didn't consider that in a real example there might be duplicate IDs desired. +1

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to subset df in your `with()`, try

```
set.seed(1)    
df <- data.frame(a=sample(1:10,10), b = sample(1:10,10),ID = sample(letters[1:10]))
plot(a~b,data = df)
with(df[1:5,], text(a~b, labels = ID [1:5]))
```